# Garbage Text Next to Git Chunk Header

Tags: git

Every time I do a `diff` with Git, I see that there's this some sort of garbage text next to the chunk header.

```
diff --git a/filename.php b/filename.php
index ddfe2f6..2209bdc 100644
--- a/filename.php
+++ b/filename.php
@@ -654,9 +654,7 @@ sessionStorage.removeItem('a'); <-- This is what I'm talking about
```

That JavaScript statement is there on every chunk header, not just one. I should probably also mention that this only happens on one specific branch. What could be the cause of this? More importantly, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all diff/patch tools point of view, this is nothing more than a noise or comment - it is totally ignored by all other tools.

However, in practice for most source code git tools like git diff generate here function name that contained this change. In other words, just by looking at commit diff, you can quickly tell what function this commit has touched.

In your case it did not look like function name, but probably only because `git diff` was not optimized to deal with javascript files, and somehow got confused.

I don't think you need to be concerned about this. If you are really so inclined, try to see if this line starts from 1st position and indent it, so it does not look like function name from git point of view.

Comment: Well, indenting it doesn't do anything. But it doesn't really matter though. I just thought that I screwed up somewhere when using Git and that this was caused by it.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` has code that attempts to recognize, based on the source file language, what function the diff is within. Here it's decided, due to some poor heuristic or oddly-formatted source code, that the function is named `sessionStorage.removeItem('a');`. In practice I find that this feature doesn't work well for anything but C, but you might find a way to change it by passing `--show-function-line` to the diff command, or perhaps `diff.xfuncname` in some git config somewhere.